# Creating a waveform representation with standard library python

Tags: python, numpy, wav, waveform

I'm creating a waveform representation of a wav file and was curious what the best possible methods to go about this efficiently in python using the standard library. Some audio files could be minutes long.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, numpy isn't part of the stdlib.

Comment: my bad. Didn't know that. I guess standard library with the except of numpy.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "creating a waveform representation"? You mean a graphical representation of the waveform (i.e., a graph of sample value vs. time)? If so, are you looking to generate a 200000x200 PNG file, to draw an animated graph in a Tk window in real-time, or… ?

Comment: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GV_aYt3elV0/T84nErDNJ3I/AAAAAAAAAWI/me1tOJOqAm0/s1600/Waveform.jpg Something like this. This is for representation in autodesk maya. It will be a animation curve.

Comment: Not stdlib, but I'd still consider looking at combining [audiolab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.audiolab/) ([docs](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/audiolab/sphinx/overview.html)) and [matplotlib](http://www.ar.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/members/david/softwares/audiolab/sphinx/overview.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TimeSide](https://github.com/yomguy/TimeSide) library solves this problem in a very simple way, while providing some more interesting graphs.

I had this same problem and implemented the algorithm suggested by synthesizerpatel, later I discovered this library and got some better results.

Comment: Ah, missed the part you said "standard library". Anyway, this question is one of the first resources I found, hope TimeSide solves someone's problem.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html - stdlib for reading wav files. [A simple example of using it.](http://www.bravegnu.org/blog/python-wave.html)

Off the top of my head this is how I'd do it (pseudocode)

```
fmts = (None, "=B", "=h", None, "=l")
fmt = fmts[sampwidth]
dcs  = (None, 128, 0, None, 0)
dc = dcs[sampwidth]

image_width = 600
image_height = 300
chunk_size = len(wavefile.getnframes()) / image_width

def unpacker(frame):
    return struct.unpack(fmt, frame)[0]

for i in range(chunk_size):
    value = math.avg([unpacker(x) for x in wavefile.read_frames(chunk_size)])
    # and then use value * 300 to figure out the vertical position for the pixel.
```

There are a variety of libraries you could use instead of writing an image, svg for example.

Comment: Additionally: An example of a module that includes C code (that could _Easily_ be converted to Python code instead..) https://github.com/superjoe30/PyWaveform

Comment: This is awesome, but i'm really just in need of an amplitude array from a wav file. I'm pretty sure I can work from here though!